# Connect to multiple FTP servers in sequence using ftp.exe (with batch file generated by VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to retrieve a particular file from multiple FTP servers. those server details are stored in Excel file. So I am writing VBA code to generate a `.bat` file.

Code:

```
Const script = "C:\Users\xyz.abc\trial.bat"
Dim fileno As Integer
Dim retval As Variant
fileno = FreeFile
Open script For Output As #fileno
Dim i As Integer

Print #fileno, "open " & Cells(2, 2).Value     'server ip
Print #fileno, Cells(2, 3).Value         'username
Print #fileno, Cells(2, 4).Value         'password
Print #fileno, "cd " & Cells(2, 5).Value    'path 
Print #fileno, "get " & Cells(2, 6).Value     'filename
Print #fileno, "bye"
Print #fileno, "open " & Cells(3, 2).Value       'server ip
Print #fileno, Cells(3, 3).Value         'username
Print #fileno, Cells(3, 4).Value       'password
Print #fileno, "cd " & Cells(3, 5).Value        'path
Print #fileno, "get " & Cells(3, 6).Value      'filename
Print #fileno, "bye"

Close #fileno
```

The problem I am facing is it is logging to the first server, retrieving file and then stopping. It's not going on to next server login. Individually it is working for both servers. Help me with this multiple logins through `.bat` file.

Comment: What happens if you add `Print #fileno, SLEEP 10` before `Print #fileno, "open " & Cells(3, 2).Value`? Also you may want to fully qualify your cells object. For example `Cells(2, 2).Value` should be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bye` command exits the `ftp.exe`.

You want to use the `close` command (or its `disconnect` alias) to disconnect only.

Use the `bye` only at the very end, after the last server.

Comment: thank you for your help. now it is working perfectly